# Matching a value in 2 D array

Tags: perl, awk, matching

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $value = $ARGV[1];

my @grabbed;

open (FILE, $file);

while (<FILE>) {
    if (/alignment#  residue#/) {
            push @grabbed, $_;
            while (<FILE>) {
            last if /^$/;
            push @grabbed, $_;
            }
    }
}
close (FILE);


my $line= `awk '  {if(\$2==$value)} ' @grabbed`;

print $line;
```

Problem :

1.First, I don't know if its possible to do awk on an array or not?
2. I am trying to match a value, existing on the second column of the 2-D array (@grabbed). The @grabbed will look like this :

```
     7         1         M     1.000         6                .VPMLG     66.63
     8         2         S     1.000        10            .QINTSARKG     66.63
     9         3         V     1.000        13         .KTAVFPRGQMSL     66.63
    10         4         L     1.000         7               .SLAKFT     66.63
    11         5         L     1.000        14        .ALSVQWIKMRYPF     66.63
    12         6         R     1.000        16      .DERSAVGTNQLYMIP     66.63
    13         7         S     1.000        18    .GDTHPKRSALFCIQVYN     66.63
    14         8         G     1.000        17     .DRFLENGAQPSTYCHM     66.63
    15         9         L     1.000        19   .NDHPELASVKRCWFGTQI     66.63
    16        10         G     1.000        18    .RLDPEGFTYAVCIKNMH     66.63
```

I am trying to match and grab the line in which column 2 is of value "9".

Comment: Mmm... for this of questions the university was created. Did you try with a recursive function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to swith to `awk` when that job can be done with `perl` too.

```
for ( @grabbed ) {
    my @f = split;
    if ( $f[1] == $value ) {
        push @line, $_;
    }
}
```

Comment: ....... push @line, $_; } print @line"\n"; } This is creating a never ending loop. Can you point me to the problem?

Comment: After the `for` loop all lines witch matches the condition will be saved in the `@line` array.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that by "2D Array" you mean an array of strings, each string being a whitespace-delimited list of values.

Perl is made for this sort of thing.  You could use the other answer's suggestion of splitting each line and looking at each value; however, a simple regular expression would be faster.  Replace your awk line with something like this:

```
foreach (@grabbed)
{
     #Match the beginning of the line, possibly some whitespace, 
     #then some digits, then more whitespace, then the contents of $value
     if (/^\s*\d+\s+$value/)
     {
          #The line matched: do stuff
     }
}
```

Also, will you ever need to look at the lines that don't match?  If not, it would be much more efficient not to put the whole file into an array; instead, just do all of your processing in the `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks. I have codes later on which will use this array for different stuff. One problem though am facing now is that when I put $value = 9, it grabs lines with 9, 19, 90-99. How do I limit this ONLY till 9?

Comment: Also, as there are similar cases for matching in different columns, won't regexp be "hard-coding" it?

Comment: Solved it by if (/^\s*\d+\s+$position\s+/). Still would love if someone could help with a more general way to look through a column. The best would be if I could pass an argument such that "if $grabbed[$column] = ....{print the line}"

Comment: If you really want to think of your input as columns, split each line into an array as in Birei's answer.  You can also take this approach further and make a true 2D array structure using references:
`my @2d; while (<FILE>) { push @2d, [ split ]; }`
Now you can access a particular element like so:
`if ($2d[$row][$column] == $value) { #do stuff }`
This is probably the way to go if you are going to do a lot of processing on particular columns.